# YII2 model relations output gridview

Tags: yii2

I have the following relations in yii2 model:

```
    public function getJobInfos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(JobInfo::className(), ['ID' => 'ID']);
    }
```

Tbl JobInfo:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobInfo](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Parameter] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](255) NULL,
....
```

The access to JobInfo in the GridView **works**:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'ID',
            [
                'label' => 'Strings',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    $strings = [];

                    foreach($data->jobInfos as $JobInfo) {

                        $strings[] = $JobInfo->Value;

                    }

                    return implode(',', $strings);

                },

            ],


            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Now all contents from JobInfo are loaded into the strings column.

Now how can I select a new column for a set:
$JobInfo->Parameter (Label) and $JobInfo->Value (Value)?
For example, if the parameter is "OrderNo"?

Unfortunately creating columns with Foreach does not work.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function now returns the value in a column. But if I create many columns, I want to construct the array only once.

```
            [
                'label' => 'column_name1',

                'value' => function($model) {
                    $datareturn = $model-> jobInfos()
                        ->where(['=', 'Parameter', 'column_name1'])
                        ->one();

                    return  $datareturn['Value'];
                    },

            ],
```

Build an array with all parameters in the model and pass it to the view in the controller?

Comment: Have you any idea for the  SearchModel?! How can I join the column_name1?

Answer (score 0):

`$data->jobInfos` return an array of `Tbl_JobInfo` objects

```
'value' => function($data) {
    return implode(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($data->jobInfos, 'Parameter', 'Value')),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

Index.php

```
[
'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
'width' => '300px',
'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
},
'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
    return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_expandableview', ['model' => 
$model]);
},
'disabled'=> function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                $rows  = $model->jobInfos;
                if (!empty($rows)) { return false;} else { return true;}
},    
'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'], 
'expandOneOnly' => true,
],
```

**Expandable View:**

```
<div class="Info-expandable-view">
<table border="0" class="table transparent">
<?php
$rows = $model->jobInfos;
foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {

//split your columns here using
//$myParameter = $value['Parameter'];
//$myValue = $value['Value'];
}
```